# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (UBUNTU 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install the Tensorflow GPU version through the native pip3 installation method. The installation was successful without any error. But, while validating the installation, I received the aforementioned error.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/batman/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Did you enable CUDA toolkit with your system?

Comment: I am not quite sure. How can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

The wheel you downloaded via pip (the official one) has been created assuming that the target system (your computer) has CUDA 9 installed and thus loadable dynamically at runtime.

The error assesses that `libcublas.so.0` can't be imported (`ImportError`), this means that the `.so` file (a dynamical library) can't be found.
Hence, you simply need to install CUDA 9 on your system in order to make it work.
In addiction to cuda, howerver, you also need to install `cudnn` v7.0  that's the Deep Neural Network library created by NVIDIA (that tensorflow uses internally).

All the installation steps are listed in the official guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Another useful reference can be this answer on askubuntu on how to install CUDA 9: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967332/how-can-i-install-cuda-9-on-ubuntu-17-10